# Can't seem to send string over a PUT request

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs

For some reason my PUT request gives an BadRequest error. I have checked what the cause is and the cause is that "gebruikersnaam" when arriving in the .NET side is null, instead of its value.

```cs
[HttpPut("naam")]
public async Task<IActionResult> VeranderNaam(string gebruikersnaam)
{
    IdentityUser user = await this._userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    Gebruiker gebruiker = this._gebruikerRepository.GetBy(user.UserName);
    Brouwer brouwer = this._brouwerRepository.GetBy(user.UserName);

    user.UserName = gebruikersnaam;
    var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        if(brouwer != null)
        {
            brouwer.Naam = gebruikersnaam;
            this._brouwerRepository.Update(brouwer);
            this._brouwerRepository.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
        else if(gebruiker != null)
        {
            gebruiker.Gebruikersnaam = gebruikersnaam;
            this._gebruikerRepository.Update(gebruiker);
            this._gebruikerRepository.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
    }

    return BadRequest();
}
```

angular code

```js
    onSubmitNaam() {
        console.log(this.gebruikersnaam.value.gebruikersnaam);
        this.authService.veranderNaam(this.gebruikersnaam.value.gebruikersnaam).subscribe(
          () => {
            this.success = "Uw naam is met success aangepast";
          }, err => {
            this.error = "Uw naam is niet aangepast";
          }
        )

        this.gebruikersnaam.reset();
    }

    veranderNaam(gebruikersnaam: string) {
        return this.http.put(`${environment.apiUrl}/gebruikers/naam`, gebruikersnaam);
    }
```

I know my form gets the value, it is sent from a form through the request, but upon arriving on the request it "becomes" null.

Comment: In angular my form on submit calls onSubmitNaam(), this method calls veranderNaam in the authService, which make an http call to the C# method VeranderNaam.

Comment: What does your browser developer tools say the request ends up looking like? (Screenshot)

Comment: I've found the solution because of your comment, the problem was I didn't use a query parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code you are submit the `body` not in a query string

```js
return this.http.put(`${environment.apiUrl}/gebruikers/naam`, gebruikersnaam);
```

So if you want your code work you can change into this

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> VeranderNaam([FromBody] string gebruikersnaam)
```

Or you can use queryParams